# Do emergency or exit lights have to be on a dedicated circuit in a commercial setting?

Tags: electrical

We hired professional at my work place and they a replacing exit/ emergency lighting and I ask what the where tieing into for power and his answer to me was the closest thing with power ourlet,heating switch ect.... and that they are led and dont draw much power is this safe or should the be run to the closest panel with a breaker?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the US (National Electrical Code territory) the emergency lighting units should be fed by the same circuit as the lighting, but it must of course be ahead of any switching.

> NEC 700.12(F) The branch circuit feeding
>   the unit equipment shall be the same branch circuit as that
>   serving the normal lighting in the area and connected ahead
>   of any local switches.  The branch circuit that feeds unit
>   equipment shall be clearly identified at the distribution
>   panel.

It's probably not an issue, but although the LED lights do not draw much power, that's not what to consider with emergency light units.  It's not the light but the charger in the unit that draws power.  I am sure it's little draw when the battery is charged, it might be a quite a bit higher when the batteries are drained, depending on the type of charger.